# phonegap 3, inappbrowser show() looses all event listeners and is not _blank anymore

Tags: events, cordova, inappbrowser

as in thread..
is there a way to call show() on an inappbrowser instance and have the "_blank" mode remaining?

ive got:

```
browser = window.open('someurl', '_blank', 'location=no,status=no,titlebar=no,fullscreen=yes,toolbar=no,hidden=yes')
```

then Im adding the listener

```
browser.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) {
                        browser.show()
})
```

and after it shows, the browser is not in "_blank" mode anymore (Im loosing all the event listeners after that and I cant attach new ones..)